# Cannot group by shared field - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a statement:

```
SELECT adherence_date,
  CASE scheduled_time
    WHEN 'morning' THEN CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ELSE null END AS morning,
  CASE scheduled_time
    WHEN 'afternoon' THEN CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ELSE null END AS afternoon,
  CASE scheduled_time
    WHEN 'evening' THEN CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ELSE null END AS evening,
  CASE scheduled_time
    WHEN 'night' THEN CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    ELSE null END AS night
FROM MEDICATION_ADHERENCES
WHERE PATIENT_ID = 10049;
```

That is outputting:

```
[
  #<MedicationAdherence:0x007f8425947860> {
                  "id" => nil,
      "adherence_date" => Thu, 27 Oct 2016,
             "morning" => 1,
           "afternoon" => nil,
             "evening" => nil,
               "night" => nil
  },
   #<MedicationAdherence:0x007f8425947360> {
                  "id" => nil,
      "adherence_date" => Thu, 27 Oct 2016,
             "morning" => nil,
           "afternoon" => 1,
             "evening" => nil,
               "night" => nil
  },
   #<MedicationAdherence:0x007f8425946d98> {
                  "id" => nil,
      "adherence_date" => Thu, 27 Oct 2016,
             "morning" => nil,
           "afternoon" => nil,
             "evening" => 1,
               "night" => nil
  },
   #<MedicationAdherence:0x007f8425946aa0> {
                  "id" => nil,
      "adherence_date" => Thu, 27 Oct 2016,
             "morning" => nil,
           "afternoon" => nil,
             "evening" => nil,
               "night" => 1
  }
]
```

I'd like it to group the results by `adherence_date` so it returns

```
#<MedicationAdherence:0x007f8425946aa0> {
                "id" => nil,
    "adherence_date" => Thu, 27 Oct 2016,
           "morning" => 1,
         "afternoon" => 1,
           "evening" => 1,
             "night" => 1
}
```

But when I add `GROUP BY ADHERENCE_DATE` it returns the error `OCIError: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

What am I not understanding here? I'm running oracle-12c

**EDIT**

The MedicationAdherence record looks like:

```
MedicationAdherence {
                 :id => :integer,
     :adherence_date => :date,
     :scheduled_time => :string,
    :acknowledged_at => :datetime,
         :patient_id => :integer,
         :created_at => :datetime,
         :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with

```
SELECT
  adherence_date,
  patient_id,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'morning'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as morning,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'afternoon' then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as afternoon,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'evening'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as evening,
  sum(case when scheduled_time = 'night'     then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as night
FROM medication_adherences
GROUP BY adherence_date, patient_id
```

Answered in this question: [Aggregating multiple records by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046022/aggregating-multiple-records-by-date)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an aggregation function for the rest of the columns.  I am guessing you want:

```
SELECT adherence_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN scheduled_time = 'morning' AND acknowledged_at is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS morning,
       SUM(CASE WHEN scheduled_time = 'afternoon' AND acknowledged_at is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS afternoon,
       SUM(CASE WHEN scheduled_time = 'evening' AND acknowledged_at is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS evening,
       SUM(CASE WHEN scheduled_time = 'night' AND acknowledged_at is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0
           END) AS night
FROM MEDICATION_ADHERENCES
WHERE PATIENT_ID = 10049
GROUP BY adherence_date;
```

Not only is the nested `case` more complicated, but it is not doing what you want.  `when null` never matches, because `null` is not equal to `null`.

Comment: I'm getting `OCIError: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` when I run your sql. Not sure where the missing `)` is though...

Comment: @theartofbeing . . . I left the `when` off the `case`.