# Aggregating multiple records by date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Model that looks like:

```
MedicationAdherence {
                 :id => :integer,
     :adherence_date => :date,
     :scheduled_time => :string,
    :acknowledged_at => :datetime,
         :patient_id => :integer,
         :created_at => :datetime,
         :updated_at => :datetime
}
```

I have 7 records (same `patient_id`):

```
{ id: 1, adherence_date: 2017-10-01, scheduled_time: 'morning', acknowledged_at: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:59:19 UTC +00:00 }
{ id: 2, adherence_date: 2017-10-01, scheduled_time: 'afternoon', acknowledged_at: nil }
{ id: 3, adherence_date: 2017-10-01, scheduled_time: 'night', acknowledged_at: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:59:19 UTC +00:00 }
{ id: 4, adherence_date: 2017-10-02, scheduled_time: 'morning', acknowledged_at: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:59:19 UTC +00:00 }
{ id: 5, adherence_date: 2017-10-02, scheduled_time: 'afternoon', acknowledged_at: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:59:19 UTC +00:00 }
{ id: 6, adherence_date: 2017-10-02, scheduled_time: 'evening', acknowledged_at: Tue, 31 Oct 2017 19:59:19 UTC +00:00 }
{ id: 7, adherence_date: 2017-10-02, scheduled_time: 'night', acknowledged_at: nil }
```

My desired outcome is to group the records above into the following output:

```
{
    "adherence_date" => 2017-10-1,
           "morning" => 1,
         "afternoon" => 0,
           "evening" => nil,
             "night" => 1
},
{
    "adherence_date" => 2017-10-2,
           "morning" => 1,
         "afternoon" => 1,
           "evening" => 1,
             "night" => 0
}
```

When there is no-record (evening 2017-10-1) it should return nil. When there is a record but no acknowledged_at it should return `false` (0), and when there is acknowledged_at returns `true`(1)

Below is the query I used to try and combine all this data, but it gives me duplicate records. How can I sum my data into what I have above...I'm sure there's a simplier way to do this

```
WITH
  adherences AS (
    SELECT * FROM medication_adherences WHERE patient_id = 10049
  ),

  morning AS (
    SELECT adherence_date,
      CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as morning
    FROM adherences
    WHERE scheduled_time = 'morning'
  ),

  afternoon as (
    SELECT adherence_date,
      CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as afternoon
    FROM adherences
    WHERE scheduled_time = 'afternoon'
  ),

  evening as (
    SELECT adherence_date,
      CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as evening
    FROM adherences
    WHERE scheduled_time = 'evening'
  ),

  night as (
    SELECT adherence_date,
      CASE acknowledged_at WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as night
    FROM adherences
    WHERE scheduled_time = 'night'
  )

SELECT morning.morning, afternoon.afternoon, evening.evening, night.night, adherences.adherence_date
FROM adherences
LEFT JOIN morning ON morning.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
LEFT JOIN afternoon ON afternoon.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
LEFT JOIN evening ON evening.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
LEFT JOIN night ON night.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
```

I'm running `oracle-12c`

**EDIT**

Looks like I had to add `GROUP BY morning.morning, afternoon.afternoon, evening.evening, night.night, adherences.adherence_date` to my query for it to properly group by. Is there a simpler way to aggregate this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `(patient_id, adherence_date, scheduled_time)` is unique in your table, meaning that a patient can book once per "slot" and date.

```
with medication_adherences  as(
-- This is your test data
   select 10049 as patient_id, 1 as id, date '2017-10-01' as adherence_date, 'morning'    as scheduled_time, timestamp '2017-10-31 19:59:19' as acknowledged_at from dual union all
   select 10049 as patient_id, 2 as id, date '2017-10-01' as adherence_date, 'afternoon'  as scheduled_time, null                            as acknowledged_at from dual union all                          
   select 10049 as patient_id, 3 as id, date '2017-10-01' as adherence_date, 'night'      as scheduled_time, timestamp '2017-10-31 19:59:19' as acknowledged_at from dual union all
   select 10049 as patient_id, 4 as id, date '2017-10-02' as adherence_date, 'morning'    as scheduled_time, timestamp '2017-10-31 19:59:19' as acknowledged_at from dual union all
   select 10049 as patient_id, 5 as id, date '2017-10-02' as adherence_date, 'afternoon'  as scheduled_time, timestamp '2017-10-31 19:59:19' as acknowledged_at from dual union all
   select 10049 as patient_id, 6 as id, date '2017-10-02' as adherence_date, 'evening'    as scheduled_time, timestamp '2017-10-31 19:59:19' as acknowledged_at from dual union all
   select 10049 as patient_id, 7 as id, date '2017-10-02' as adherence_date, 'night'      as scheduled_time, null                            as acknowledged_at from dual
)
select adherence_date
      ,sum(case when scheduled_time = 'morning'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as morning
      ,sum(case when scheduled_time = 'afternoon' then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as afternoon
      ,sum(case when scheduled_time = 'evening'   then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as evening
      ,sum(case when scheduled_time = 'night'     then nvl2(acknowledged_at,1,0) end) as night
  from medication_adherences 
 where patient_id = 10049
 group
    by adherence_date;
```

The logic works like this:

- if acknowledged_at is     null then we aggregate 0 (via nvl2)
- if acknowledged_at is **not** null then we aggregate 1  (via nvl2)
- if there is no record for this timeslot we aggregate null (since case when ... failed)

Comment: When I've viewing this View through my ORM (ActiveRecord/Rails) it's interpreting the morning, afternoon, evening, night fields as integers instead of booleans. Is that because of the `sum` function?

Comment: they are actually integers and not boolean :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Oracle developer, but what you are missing here is the group by clause... you can replace MAX with SUM if you want to count the number of records...

```
Select MAX(Morning.Morning), MAX(afternoon.afternoon), MAX(evening.evening), MAX(night.night), adherences.adherence_date
FROM medication_adherences 
LEFT JOIN morning ON morning.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
LEFT JOIN afternoon ON afternoon.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
LEFT JOIN evening ON evening.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
LEFT JOIN night ON night.adherence_date = adherences.adherence_date
WHERE patient_id = 10049
GROUP BY adherences.adherence_date
```

I would get rid of adherences CTE, as we don't really need it... You still need Morning, Afternoon, etc CTEs on top of this query.

Comment: I tried adding GROUP BY but I get the error: `OCIError: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: If you tried the query that I have provided above, I had missed out adherences.adherence_date... updated. As I mentioned, I don't use Oracle RDBMS so was not able to check the syntax